# Visualizing D language coverage results in the fringe

Tags: fringe

I want to visualize coverage data from the D compiler DMD on the fringe. [This packages](https://github.com/mattharrison/pycoverage.el) makes use of `linum-.*`. Is this the best way to visualize such things in the margin?

The Emacs package [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/blob/master/diff-hl.el) seems to be a good template. But does it have to be this complicated?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, linum uses the left margin.  The fringe itself can only hold a bitmap at a specified position, making it rather unflexible.

Comment: So is `linum` the best way forward with this, then?

Comment: I wouldn't know, just pointing out that answering your question becomes impossible if the base assumption is wrong.  Please reformulate your question.